# Dynamic LINQ where query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I'm using dynamic LINQ to create a query from given columns the user selects for a given search.

e.g. simplified code ex:

```
var counter = 0;
var predicate = string.Empty;
foreach(var field in selectedFields)
{
    predicate += field + ".Contains(@" + counter + ") ||"; 
    // logical OR, without it the SQL generates AND
}    
predicate = predicate.Remove(predicate.LastIndexOf("||", 2));
query = query.Where(predicate, searchvalues);
```

This code generates the given SQL query

```
(([t0].[Field1] LIKE 'searchstring') OR ([t0].[Field2] LIKE 'searchstring'))
```

Which is correct, albeit what i want to do is be able to use wildcards, when i try to enter let's say, a percent character, the SQL generated is

```
(([t0].[field1] LIKE 'searchstring' ESCAPE '~') OR ([t0].[field2] LIKE 'searchstring' ESCAPE '~'))
```

Is there a way to use wildcards in the searchstring while using dynamic L2S?

Regards

Comment: Are you using Linq to Sql or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `.StartsWith || .EndsWith || .Contains`

That might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it - i would upvote you but i need 15 rep :/

Comment: Cool, I was not sure either, you learn something new everyday I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Linq to Sql then you can make use of the [SqlMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx) helper class.

One of the methods is [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340785.aspx) which maps onto the SQL LIKE clause.  If you need it, it is more flexible than using `.StartsWith` etc